# Sytem table name for schema

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA') 
   FROM DUAL;
```

Gives the current Schema, I am trying to build function `DB2` equivalent to Oracle `SYS_CONTEXT`. I am not getting how oracle is selecting schema name. Any system table where it stores all schema name is some one have any insight please help

Answer (score 1):

> Any system table where it stores all schema name

You could use the ***_USERS** view to get the schema names. In **Oracle**, **schema name** and **username** are synonymous.

For example, to get all the schema names:

```
SELECT username FROM all_users;
```

To see the current user:

```
SELECT username FROM user_users;
```

If you are using **SQL*Plus**, you could simply do:

```
SHOW USER
```

Comment: yea that is know i want to get current schema name,,,Suppose you are logged in as user1 and then alter session to user 2.. Now i want to get user2 as current schema....SYS_CONTEXT is the solution but i am building this function in DB so want to know how oracle do it in the backend my view is there might be some table storing schema name n some flag might be set to true when session is altered

Comment: @oracle It's not clear what you are trying to do. What is the alter statement you are using?

Comment: I want to know how SYS_CONTEXT works when you give parameter as CURRENT_SCHEMA. System table from where it fetches schema name

Comment: Oracle alter statement is alter session set current_schema=user2 now your current schema is schema2 how to get this without using sys_context